# selecting option from select element with php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a database field `country` which I want to query and select that country option from a select element. Is there any way to do this without adding:

```
if (query->country == "<some country>"){echo "selected"}
```

in every single option tag? As there are hundreds of country options. Here is a little example of the code. Thank you.

```
$query = $query->fetch_object();

// which ever country is held in the variable `$query->country` should be selected

echo"<select>
       <option>Afghanistan</option>
       ......
       ......
       <option>Zimbabwe</option>
     </select>";
```

Comment: You can do it easily if you've an array of countries. Simply match the value and echo when it matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't you have a list of all countries on your server?

```
$countries = ["Afghanistan", ... , "Zimbabwe"];
```

You could do something like this:

```
$selection = "Some country";

echo "<select>";

foreach($countries as $country)
{
    if($country == $selection)
        echo "<option selected>" . $country . "</option>";
    else
        echo "<option>" . $country . "</option>";
}

echo "</select>";
```

Comment: I will use this method. I just have to make one mammoth of a country array:).Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The IF still needs to be "placed" on every `<option>` but as a programmer you should do something like this:

```
$options = array( 'Afghanistan', '...', 'Zimbabwe' );

foreach( $options as $option )
{
    $selected = ( $query->country == $option )? ' selected': '';
    echo '<option' . $selected . '>' . $option . '</option>';
}
```

and if you're unfamiliar with ternary operator, the `$selected = ...` part above can be written like this:

```
if ( $query->country == $option )
{
    $selected = ' selected';
}
else
{
    $selected = '';
}
```